# How much energy could a human body be converted into?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

How many people have read Eragon, the Inheritance Cycle and wondered how much energy Galbatorix turned himself into? Okay, maybe it's just me ;)

So mass is destroyed in a nuclear reaction to create the energy, right? Well, if the entirety of a human body were converted to energy, how much energy would be created and how much damage would be done/matter displaced?

I've tried to figure out how much energy the human body would become if the mass were converted to energy and came up with about 3.24 x 10^{35} J (for an 80 kg male) *IF* I did the maths right. I just used $E=mc^2$ but I don't know if that's correct and a terribly specific hypothetical question like this doesn't get may answers on Google...

Thank you for all answers everyone! :D

Comment: BTW, Google can do calculations like this. `80 kg * c^2` returns $7.19004143 × 10^{18}$ joules.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the person's mass is $80 kg$ (so he would weigh about $800$ Newtons) then
the amount of energy released if all of this person’s mass was converted to energy is

$$E = 80c^2 = 7.2 \times 10^{18} J$$

This is a huge amount of energy. By comparison, the amount of energy released by the bomb dropped on Hiroshima in WW2
was about $6.3 \times 10^{13} J$.

> how much energy would be created and how much damage would be done/matter displaced?

This means that if this mans mass was completely converted to energy, it would be the equivalent of detonating $1,000$ Hiroshima bombs
simultaneously. If you look at the damage done by this blast alone and multiply it by $1,000$, this should give you the idea of the
amount of dmamge. Or think about $1,000$ average size (major) cities throughout the world all destroyed simultaneously!

> So mass is destroyed in a nuclear reaction to create the energy, right?

It’s not “destroyed”. Rather, it is converted to energy. Remember that matter/energy can never be destroyed
(or created).